# send blobs to server while MediaRecorder is 'recording'

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, blob

I want to build recording app. So it will do POST HTTP request to send blobs while the app is recording and ensure the file is saved before the stop record button is fired.

I used event '''MediaRecorder.ondataavailable''' but it doesn't seems like a solution since it's executed only when '''MediaRecorder.stop()''' is executed.

Actually I inspired by Bugbluebutton Recording they do the same business process but i don't know how they are work (technically)

Comment: any solution you found?

Comment: i decided to use openvidu, it works the same with my question